# IE 8 showing empty string as "null"

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am getting json result from a service and some of the field and empty strings. All other browsers displays the empty string well, but IE 8 shows it "null",

Anyone who has ever had the same issue and got solution?

Comment: Without seeing any of your code, or the JSON itself, you're not going to get any good answers.

Comment: Try taking a look at this similar post if you haven't already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1543791/json-empty-string