# JSON stringify returns empty string

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, string

In Javascript I try to use stringify but it keeps returning an empty string. What is wrong here? Feel free to edit the Fiddle.

**JS**

```
values = [];
values['belopp'] = 2322;
values['test'] = 'jkee';

str = JSON.stringify(values);

console.log(values);
console.log(str); // Expected to show a json array
```

**JS Fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/L4t4vtvd/

Comment: values shuld be {}  not []

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are trying to use something that is meant for an object on an array.

```
values = {};
values['belopp'] = 2322;
values['test'] = 'jkee';

str = JSON.stringify(values);
```

This is the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L4t4vtvd/1/).

Comment: you can also stringify arrays, what are you talking about?

Answer (score 4):

You are stringifying an `array ([])`, not an `object ({})` Therefore, `values = {};`